# API Request Fails immediately in iOS share extension

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire, share-extension

Hi I'm using a share extension to post some data to my server using API request (Alamofire), the problem is that the request fails immediately and I don't know how to make it work, I read on some articles that I must use URLSession to send the request in the background but I couldn't find any example to how to make it work with alamofire, here is my code in share extension ViewController:

```
override func didSelectPost() {

    MessageHTTPHelper.submitMessage(contains: contentText, completion: { (response) in
        self.showAlert(title: "Result", message: response.result.isSuccess ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILURE")
    })

}
```

The `MessageHTTPHelper.submitMessage` is a helper function that I defined and it works in the main app perfectly
I don't care about the response, I just want to send the request without any callbacks, can you please give me an example of sending a request in iOS share extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of search and tests and fails, finally, [this solution](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1922#issuecomment-274246592) worked for me!

and here is my code in `didSelectPost()`

let body: Parameters =  [
        "version": Configs.currentReleaseVersion,
        "content": cleanTextContent
    ]

```
let request = HTTPHelper.makeHTTPRequest(route: "message",
                           headers: HTTPHelper.defaultAuthHTTPHeaders,
                           verb: .post,
                           body: body,
                           apiV1Included: true)
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.background", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent)

request.responseJSON(queue: queue, options: .allowFragments) { (response) in
    if response.result.isFailure {
        guard let message = response.error?.localizedDescription else {
            self.dismiss()
            return
        }
        self.showAlert(title: "Error", message: message)
    }
}
```

The `HTTPHepler.makeHTTPRequest` is just a helper method which creates an Alamofire DataRequest Instance with given parameters and returns it